# Grouping by column and rows

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table like this:

```
+----+--------------+--------+----------+
| id |     name     | weight | some_key |
+----+--------------+--------+----------+
|  1 | strawberries |     12 |        1 |
|  2 | blueberries  |      7 |        1 |
|  3 | elderberries |      0 |        1 |
|  4 | cranberries  |      8 |        2 |
|  5 | raspberries  |     18 |        2 |
+----+--------------+--------+----------+
```

I'm looking for a generic request that would get me all berries where there are three entries with the same 'some_key' and one of the entries (within those three entries belonging to the same some_key) has the weight = 0

in case of the sample table, expected output would be:

```
1 strawberries
2 blueberries
3 cranberries
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show us the SQL you have tried.

Comment: @LutzHorn everything i've tried has been nonsense... how would that help?

Comment: @DxTx best case: that should be a parameter.... so i could get 1 or 2 with the same key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this-

```
SELECT some_key,
SUM(weight) --Sample aggregations on column 
FROM your_table
GROUP BY some_key
HAVING COUNT(*) = 3 -- If you wants at least 3 then use >=3
AND SUM(CASE WHEN weight = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) >= 1
```

As per your edited question, you can try this below-

```
SELECT id, name
FROM your_table
WHERE some_key IN (
    SELECT some_key
    FROM your_table
    GROUP BY some_key
    HAVING COUNT(*) = 3 -- If you wants at least 3 then use >=3
    AND SUM(CASE WHEN weight = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) >= 1
)
```

Comment: I would write `SUM(CASE WHEN weight = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) >= 1` as `count(*) filter (where weight = 0) >= 1` because I think it's more obvious what it should do - but that is a personal preference

Comment: Nice to hear that is helped.

Answer (score 2):

As you want to include non-grouped columns, I would approach this with window functions:

```sql
select id, name
from (
  select id, 
         name, 
         count(*) over w as key_count,
         count(*) filter (where weight = 0) over w as num_zero_weight 
  from fruits
  window w as (partition by some_key) 
) x
where x.key_count = 3
  and x.num_zero_weight >= 1
```

The `count(*) over w` counts the number of rows in that group (= partition) and the `count(*) filter (where weight = 0) over w` counts how many of those have a weight of zero.

The `window w as ...` avoids repeating the same `partition by` clause for the window functions.

Online example: https://rextester.com/SGWFI49589

Comment: works as well, but answer from @mkRabbani seems simpler.
thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Try doing this.

Table structure and sample data

```sql
CREATE TABLE tmp (
  id int, 
  name varchar(50), 
  weight int, 
  some_key int
);
INSERT INTO tmp 
VALUES 
  ('1', 'strawberries', '12', '1'), 
  ('2', 'blueberries', '7', '1'), 
  ('3', 'elderberries', '0', '1'), 
  ('4', 'cranberries', '8', '2'), 
  ('5', 'raspberries', '18', '2');
```

Query

```sql
SELECT t1.*
FROM   tmp t1
       INNER JOIN (SELECT some_key
                   FROM   tmp
                   GROUP  BY some_key
                   HAVING Count(some_key) >= 3
                          AND Min(Abs(weight)) = 0) t2
               ON t1.some_key = t2.some_key;
```

Output

```
+-----+---------------+---------+----------+
| id  |     name      | weight  | some_key |
+-----+---------------+---------+----------+
|  1  | strawberries  |     12  |        1 |
|  2  | blueberries   |      7  |        1 |
|  3  | elderberries  |      0  |        1 |
+-----+---------------+---------+----------+
```

Online Demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/70cca/26/0

---

<sup>Thank you, @mkRabbani for reminding me about the negative values.</sup>

<sup>**Further reading**

- ABS() Function - [Link01](https://www.w3resource.com/PostgreSQL/abs-function.php), [Link02](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_abs.asp)

- HAVING Clause - [Link01](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/postgresql/postgresql_having_clause), [Link02](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_having.asp)</sup>

Comment: I also thought about Min(weight) = 0 first, but changed my mind considering the scenario if there are Negative value exists.

Comment: @mkRabbani Totally forget about that.  Ty. Updated. +1